# Getting "INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE" error message when try to update Salesforce Contact objet via Java(EnterpriseWSDL)

Tags: java, salesforce

I tried to update Department field in Salesforce Contact object. I got this error response : 
"INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE Unable to create/update fields: Name. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set".

When I tried the Opportunity object(Fields : Amount, stageName), the update succeeded.

I checked the field security levels on both objects' fields. Security levels are same but I am not able to update the Contact object. Could anyone help me with this issue? [Stage(opportunity) field access levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac3JQ.png) - 
[Department(Contact) field access levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrIGf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates "Unable to create/update fields: Name" not the department field. The name field on contact is a read-only field computed from lastName & firstName fields, you can't send it in an update request. You need to update your code to just send the fields you want to change.